# parametro X-Frame-Options: DENY no lo encuentro en ningun lugar configurado

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, debian

dentro de mi sitio wordpress tengo configurada la cabecera X-Frame-Options: DENY el problema es que he revisado todos los archivos de configuracion y no lo encuentro en ningun lugar.
revise
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf , /etc/apache2/sites-available/ , en mi proyecto en wordpress revise el .htaccess y el wp-config.php

Comment: ¿Está tu sitio alojado en un *shared host*? Es probable que esa configuración sea global y debas hablar con el soporte de tu proveedor de *host*.

Comment: Esta en una vm dentro de google cloud

Answer (score 0):

Búscalo como configuración:

`grep -nir 'X-Frame-options' /etc/apache2/`

Según la versión y la distro la directiva puede que esté enforced ( `always` ) en `ssl.conf` `security.conf` `ssl-params.conf`

Algunos ejemplos:

- el primer resultado es un backup en un upgrade
- el segundo resultado está comentado con `#`
- el tercer resultado es el default

```
/etc/apache2/conf-available/security.conf.dpkg-old:70:Header set X-Frame-Options: "sameorigin"
/etc/apache2/conf-available/ssl-params.conf:11:# Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:16:Header set X-Frame-Options: "sameorigin"
```

Comment: use el comando para buscar las configuraciones dentro de apache y me arrojo varios lugares pero todos comentados.

Comment: 1/ fijate de fijar el valor deseado en el `ssl-params.conf` ; o te creas un archivo.conf en la carpeta `conf-available`  y luego con `a2enconf` activas la configuracion, ( se crea un symlink en conf-enable) reinicias apache y verificas. un header value con always no puede ser quitado, si ya sabes que valor ponerle lo pones ahi.

Comment: 2/ cloud load balancing, cloudflare, u otro balancer, proxy, reverse proxy o edge pueden modificar el trafico. verifica en las opciones si no hay un "iframe protection" o similar. Lo habitual es agregar el header si no existe, asi que si lo especificas en el origen ( la conf de apache ) debería respetar ese header